# SharePoint Migration from Dev to Live

Tags: development, migration

I am going to be in the process of taking my dev site and putting it on live. Just wondering if there is anything I need to be aware of or any tips/software to do so?

Comment: What type of site is it? Team Site, Publishing Site? Are you using content deployment or just backup/restore?

Comment: Are we talking artifacts or content?

Comment: Its not a big surprise to me that you would advocate the developer-centric approach (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262251.aspx) ;-)
Another good reason to deploy to root folder is caching. Document libraries does not set correct age in headers, causing browser to do bundles of requests to server (304 not modified).
More on this issue http://www.kindohm.com/archive/2008/06/20/eliminating-quot304quot-status-codes-with-sharepoint-web-folder-resources.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Features, features, and more features. And solutions. Everything (and I do mean *everything*) I do is done in dev but then packaged into a feature for deployment to test/staging then production. This includes anything from page layouts, master pages, CEWP web parts, to full blown solutions with web parts, receivers and custom code.

Seriously it takes 2 minutes to slam together the feature code around whatever solution you may have. Take the wsp and deploy.

Advantages are
a) The deployment will handle pushing out all changes to all web front ends
b) You can easily pull it back if you need to
c) It can be upgraded (although it's not pretty, it is simple)
d) You take the exact same WSP and deploy to production.

An added bonus would be to get the SharePoint Installer project from CodePlex to turn your wsp into an exe you can just hand off to your network guys and let them install it.

Comment: 'Everything (and I do mean everything) I do is done in dev' - what tool do you use to "do" everything?  Directly on the site, using SP Designer, Visual Studio?

Comment: @BlueChippy Various tools but everything is packaged into a solution in Visual Studio. For example I'll create a feature for a master page with CSS, deply the feature, edit the files in SPD and fold them back into the solution for deployment to an environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools and techniques depending on what (code, content, configuration) you are trying to promote from development to production. Tell us a bit more at what your trying to accomplish and we can point you in the right direction.